# How to upload a file to kubernetes cluster for my Apps to access it?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

Lets say we have an application which accesses a file. This App is a jar which is packaged into an image and pushed to Registry for the Kubernetes to run it. But when we create the Pod, we need to configure a volume also in it. When we specify a volume we give a path, how do we place the file in that volume from lets say our virtual machine?

Please help me in understanding this with an explanation. Also should we create a storage so that its accessible from kubernetes cluster? please explain relevent topic as well to understand this.

Note: we are using azure cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to create a `ConfigMap` with the data you want to use from your application. Then you just need to mount the `ConfigMap` as a volume in the Pod's ([explained here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)) that need the data.

You can easily create a `ConfigMap` from a file like

```
kubectl create configmap your-configmap-name --from-file=/some/path/to/file
```

And then [mount it in your Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I think we can use ConfigMap, but i want to understand one more thing in this. Lets say I created "Config-Maps from directories" (Please see below for command). Could you please give me piece of code here itself as its confusing in the link you gave. I want the code to refer this volume (which i created using below command for directories) from my Pod definition and what else should i specify to load it into the pod?

Comment: I will use "kubectl create configmap game-config --from-file=docs/user-guide/configmap/kubectl" command to create config map with directories

Comment: I've updated my answer with the Pod definition and a link to an example

Comment: Just to be clear, in the above example for volume configuration you have defined configMap:  name: special-config. So the volume we need to create in the first step is "special-config" right like below.

Comment: kubectl create configmap special-config --from-file=/some/path/to/file

Comment: Yes, you provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses.